# Postgres connection pooling not working with .NET core 6 Transaction scope

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core

I am using Npgsql and Dapper for connecting to postgres db from .NET 6 application. I have enabling connection pooling in postgres connection.

please refer https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

Commands are executed inside a transaction scope. I am executing multiple commands and each command opens new connection using NpgsqlDataSource.OpenConnection method.

Getting an error when transcationscope.Complete is called. Following is the error.

Message: 
System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException : The transaction has aborted.
---- Npgsql.PostgresException : 55000: prepared transactions are disabled

We understand that this means connection is not reused as its trying to start prepared transaction. This is against what is documented in the last para of https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#systemtransactions-and-distributed-transactions
and https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#pooling

What are we doing wrong

Please help.

#edit 1 Attaching code sample

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope()) 
{
  
   using connection1 = NpgsqlConnection();
       
    await connection1.ExecuteAsync("procedure1"); 

    using connection2 = NpgsqlConnection();
    await connection2.ExecuteAsync("procedure2");
    
    transactionScope.Complete()
}



private static NpgsqlConnection NpgsqlConnection()
{
    string connectionString = "User ID=postgres;Password=*****;Host=hostName;Port=5432;Database=DBTestPostgres;Pooling=true;";
    NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString); ,
    using NpgsqlDataSource dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
    NpgsqlConnection conn = dataSource.OpenConnection();
    return conn;
}
```

I was expecting the same connection should be reused as pooling is turned on in connection string.

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/prepared-transactions/ Ideally avoid `TransactionScope` and use the normal `beginTransaction` on the connection object

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588232/does-npgsql-provider-has-support-for-transactionscope and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215180/transactionscope-nested-transactions-with-different-database-connections-sql-s

Comment: NPgSql Documentation says they fully support System.Transactions  https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#systemtransactions-and-distributed-transactions. @Charlieface.
We want to use System.Transactions.

Comment: Also, we wna to use the Pooling mechanism built into the NpgSql and make use of 
"Note that if you open and close connections to the same database inside an ambient transaction, without ever having two connections open at the same time, Npgsql internally reuses the same connection, avoiding the need for a distributed transaction."

Comment: You need to add `Enlist=true` to your connection string, and probably also enable `max_prepared_transactions` on the server

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to avoid Distributed Transactions (which is a good idea, as they have serious overhead, and also require server configuration).

[The documentation states](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#systemtransactions-and-distributed-transactions):

> Note that if you open and close connections to the same database inside an ambient transaction, without ever having two connections open at the same time, Npgsql internally reuses the same connection, avoiding the need for a distributed transaction

But you actually have two concurrent connections. You need to change your code to close the connection, by using the old style `using` block, rather than a `using` statement.

```cs
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope()) 
{
    using (var connection1 = NpgsqlConnection())
    {
        await connection1.ExecuteAsync("procedure1");
    }

    using (var connection2 = NpgsqlConnection())
    {
        await connection2.ExecuteAsync("procedure2");
    }
    
    transactionScope.Complete()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make your connection using this code.
Be sure to replace "DataBase" with the correct name of your connection string in the config file.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(provider =>
{
    var connectionString = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetConnectionString("DataBase");
    return new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
});
```

Comment: The above is a solution to use Same connection between DB calls in a DI Scope. While this is a way to solve this, NpgSql documentation says us that we dont need this if we are pooling
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#pooling.

Multipe connections to same connString opened and closed in the same transation uses a same cached transaction.  Our question is why is this not working with the above code.